# Blurry Explorer on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, gui

I've got a weird graphic issue. On my thinkpad I've got a 4k display, which I've set to FullHD and without any zoom.

The title bar of windows and also the whole explorer of windows is displayed blurry. What is weird: When press right click and the context menu appears, it is totally sharp.

Even more weird: When I make a Screenshot of blurry explorer and sharp context menu, everything on screenshot is sharp. Even when I move the window with the screenshot to the same position where the explorer was before, it's sharp.

Other applications like Google Chrome, are not affected. Apps with classic title bar (like `cmd`) are shart, but the title bar itself is blurry.

**Update:** I've added a picture from my smartphone. On the right you see the blurry explorer application, left you see a screenshot of the exact same window (using Snipping Tool).

[image: Sharp vs blurry]

A reboot does not change anything. Any hints are appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You may add some pictures taken with a phone. Have you tried reinstalling the graphics card drivers?

Comment: How are you rebooting? Restart, or shut-down and start-up?

Comment: I've added a picture from my smartphone. I tried both (reboot, shutdown) and also only log off.

Comment: What are the exact pixel dimensions of the screenshot? FullHD looks like a service mark. "Full HD" used to mean 1080p, in which case rendering a 4k sized image and downsampling to 1080p and then displaying it full-screen is going to be blurry. That would be basically 4x full scene anti-aliasing.

Comment: Did you look at the DPI settings for Windows? Also, are you using a resolution that is supported by the display? If you change the resolution to something else, does the issue go away?

Comment: When I do a screenshot it is not blurry anymore. So I think the resolution is not the problem and is supported by the display (because the screenshot is displayed properly and not blurry at all) on this display with 1920x1080. I could increase resolution to 3840x2160 but then I need to enable zoom (to 250%) and this is super annoying when you've got a second display connected, without 4k support.

Comment: native resolutio nis 4k, so use 4K and apply DPI scaling. Since WIn10 1607, MS added several DPI improvements to Win10.

Comment: I also got blurry output when I used scaling with native resolution. This was the reason I switched to FullHD. When I get a docking station for my laptop (with this 4k display), I'm using external displays. This problem seems to be Windows-made. Screenshots can get properly get displayed. So not the resolution itself is the problem.

Comment: It gets weirder, I have Windows Explorer windows beside each other on the same monitor, looking at the same folder - one is blurry and one is sharp. My main monitor is set at 125%, the other 2 at 100%. I think it depends on how Explorer was started, if it is called from an application it may inherit that app's high DPI handing settings. That's just a guess. I can't find a way to change the file explorer's DPI handling policy.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the resolution to 1920x1080, set it back to native 4K (3840x2160 usually). Of course it's going to be blurry because the resolution is lower than native.
If it doesn't help, try reinstalling the GPU driver.

Comment: You are wrong. If this would be true, screenshots I've made would not be displayed sharp. But they do. When you use the snipping tool of Windows and click on new... the tool makes a screenshot and overlays over the real desktop. Also it makes it brighter, so you can draw a rectangle for the screenshot. The blurry text becomes sharp when this overlay is dispayed. On the same display which has ne FullHD but not native resolution.

Comment: You don't understand how this works, dude. The image on the screen looks blurry because you put the resolution that monitor wasn't supposed to show. So, the screenshot tool records the image signal given by your GPU, not by your LCD/LED screen. See: https://imgur.com/69QRB5h. This is my default resolution (1600x900) and everything looks fine. Now look at this: https://imgur.com/K85VnDx. I set it to 1366x768. Everything looks blurry and stretched on my monitor, but on screenshot everything looks fine. Why? Because the signal GPU sends is different on monitor and fine on the screenshot.

Comment: Okay. You've changed the resolution and have this blurry output. Now you make a screenshot with e.g. snipping tool. Is the taken image now displayed properly? If yes, you are right. I don't understand how this works. But if the output of the screenshot is equal with the regular output (on your current screen & resolution) then it behaves differently to my issue. When I take the screenshot it is displayed properly. Crystal clear. On this display, with not-native res (1080p). I think the presentation layer of windows is the reason.

Comment: Well, the actual reason is your monitor. GPU sends an output signal to your monitor. As the resolution signal is not compatible with your monitor, the LCD/LED screen distorts the signal and shows blurry/stretched image. CRT monitors were compatible with ANY type of resolution as they had the "min-to-max" resolution output system, while LCD/LED's have only 1 native resolution. The snipping tool records the output signal given by the GPU, not the image outputten by monitor. Yeah, everything is complicated but anyway..

Comment: Yes right. But the screenshotted GPU output is displayed properly (within the image viewer) on this display, while **at the same time** the explorer GPU output is blurry. You get this, right? I can drag the sharp image viewer over the blurry explorer. The wrong resolution may cause this issue in Windows. But basically the display is able to display things in this resolution crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is several years old at this point, but this is for anybody else experiencing a similar problem.

The main problem here is that you're trying to operate the display at a resolution (FHD, 1080p) that's lower than its native resolution (4K, 2160p). The blurriness you're seeing is an artifact of scaling being done by the GPU to inflate the output to the display's resolution.

Your best bet would be to set the display's resolution back to its native resolution and adjust Windows' scaling settings. Windows has scaling built in, but it's bitmap scaling, which means some applications (legacy Win32 apps and similar) will appear blurry if the number is not a multiple of 50. For 4K, that shouldn't really be a problem. Go to Settings -> Display to change the display's scale.

Luckily, if you want a specific size (or some applications are blurry), there's an alternative method.

Go to Settings -> Display, and under "Scale and layout", click "Advanced scaling settings". Make sure the "Fix scaling for apps" switch is enabled, and then under "Custom scaling", type in a scaling size. To be on the safe side, start with a number like 125, and increase as needed. You will need to log out & back in for each change to take effect. 300+ is likely overkill and might give you problems, so proceed at your own risk and heed the given warning.

Hope this helps!